# php to json structure

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am having a hard time transferring my php array of arrays to a json object.

```
Array(
    [28] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
        ) 
        [1] => Array(
            [0] => 1 
            [1] => 18
        )
        [424] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 5
            ) 
            [1] => Array(
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 18
            )
        )
     )
)
```

After I json_encode this structure in jQuery I use the .each and get the two arrays but I cant seem to grab the [28] and [424]. Any thoughts?

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
    console.log(val); // NAME ??
    console.log(data[i][0]); // LIST 1
    console.log(data[i][1]); // LIST 2
});
```

Comment: What does `console.log(i)` yield?

Answer (score 4):

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
    console.log(i); // name
    console.log(val); //array
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON encodes keys as strings, which means that jQuery is looking for a string, not an integer.  Try accessing the arrays using strings.

Comment: `json_encode` (no flags given) will encode the array keys as object member names, not array keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
    //First iterration "this" will point to '28' array
    //Second iterration "this" will point to '424' array

    //You can use it like this, this[i][0]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP array keys `28` and `424` will be represented in the javascript variable `i` inside the callback function.

Check the docs for [`$.each` <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), they explain it in detail.

Comment: Easy enough, the examples used 'i' and I assumed it was an integer all the time. Thanks!